# jQuery Tipsy Tooltip Plugin Customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tipsy

I am using the jQuery plugin [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy) to activate tooltips when specific elements are hovered over. Currently, the tooltip appears in the middle of the element that it was triggered by, but I would like to customize the plugin so that the tooltip appears over the corresponding headline. Take a look at the example I've linked to below. The tooltip is triggered when the whole `#everything` div is hovered over, which is correct, but I would like the tooltip to appear above the headline.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JqFwP/2/

Please let me know if you need more information or further explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with tipsy plugin, but how about chaining a `mouseenter` event to `#everything`?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#everything").tipsy({
    gravity: 's'
}).mouseenter(function(){
    var top=$(this).find('h2').offset().top - 35,
        left=$(this).find('h2').offset().left - 10;
    $('.tipsy').css({
        'top': top + 'px',
        'left': left + 'px'
    });
});
```

DEMO (Single Headline): http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/JqFwP/16/

DEMO (Multiple Headlines): http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/JqFwP/17/

IMHO, I recommend you use [jQueryUI's tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) instead. I feel it would be more beneficial. Just a thought!  Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I ended up selecting this answer because it is more concise and works well for my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

You need to change this pos variable from:

```
           var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.offset(), {
                width: this.$element[0].offsetWidth,
                height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
            });
```

to:

```
           var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.offset(), {
                width: $(this).children("h2").offsetWidth,
                height: $(this).children("h2").offsetHeight
            });
```

working fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/L9BVc/8/

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating plugin's code is not the best solution from my point of view.
@Dom's approach seems great but doesn't support the "s" value for gravity's attribute of tipsy, which shows the tooltip in the center of the element tipsy was binded.

My first thought was to detect mouse enter for the container "div" and bind tipsy to the inner header (h2). That won't work for small headers since h2 by default is displayed as a block and takes 100% of the container element.

You have to add some CSS styling to the header which will break up your content.
So I have managed to build up a solution where I wrap h2 contents with a span element in order to keep things clean and clear.

Manipulating your original HTML

```
<div id="everything" original-title="The whole kit and caboodle.">
     <h2>Working with really great and awesome headlines</h2>
     ....
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="everything" original-title="The whole kit and caboodle.">
     <h2><span original-title="The whole kit and caboodle.">Working with really great and awesome headlines</span></h2>
</div>
```

Least but not last, I have polished my code in order to bind tipsy only once for each div container, since I wasn't able to find out how the plugin manipulates the DOM

**Updated version as @585connor suggested**

http://jsfiddle.net/JqFwP/22/

**Update vol2:**
There is a another issue with my approach, if the headline is too short, the tooltip is stripped outside of the DOM.
I have managed to solve this using a class in the wrapping span and some css code.

Proof of this issue
http://jsfiddle.net/JqFwP/25/

My workaround
http://jsfiddle.net/JqFwP/24/

Comment: In your example, when a user hovers over a headline then down to body text (within the same div), the tooltip disappears.

Comment: Your comment was straight to the point. Hovering the headline triggers the tooltip and the makes the mouseenter and mouseleave events stop working. I have added an extra parameter to tipsy init in order to get my hands on tipsy manually as it is suggested in the documentation, `trigger: 'manual'` was the key to fix the bug. Check my revision on the fiddle above.